# likewise-open with WIN AD or ldap-auth-client with openldap server

Tags: openldap, likewise

I will like to know which of the following combinations is popular;

likewise-open with WIN AD or ldap-auth-client with openldap server

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both can be use as per your scenario.

likewise-open Can be use when you have centralised authentication with AD which server is on Windows.

And ldap-auth-client is usable with Ldap.

So you can use it as per your scenario.